# Simplifying a fraction of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is a really simple question. All I want to know is how it goes from that first line of the equation to the second line, what is it they're doing. I'm just missing something, can someone explain.
$$
\begin{split}
H(z) &= \frac{0.3249(z+1)}{(z-1)+0.3249z+0.3249}\\
H(z) &= \frac{0.3249(z+1)}{1.3249z-0.6751}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: $\begin{align}{\rm The\ denominator\ } &=\ \color{#c00}z\!-\!1 + \color{#c00}{az}\!+\!a\\[.2em] &=\ \color{#c00}{(a\!+\!1)z} +a\!-\!1\ \ \ {\rm  for}\ \ \ a = 0.3249\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the denominator can be simplified:
$$
(z-1) + 0.3249z + 0.3249 = (z + 0.3249z) + (0.3249-1) = 1.3249z - 0.6751.
$$